# strange behaviour with ulimit on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: mac, macos, ulimit

I get some very strange behaviour when working with ulimit.
I just open up a new shell

```
Hector:~ robertj$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited 
open files                      (-n) 256 
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 532
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Ok, that seems to be the default even thou I set
the limit on files within /etc/launchd.conf to be unlimit.
But that is another question for another day.

Now I increase the number of files to 1024 and let have a look unto the new settings again.

```
 Hector:~ robertj$ ulimit -n 1024
 Hector:~ robertj$ ulimit -a | grep open
 open files                      (-n) 1024
```

Okay, that works. cool! Now lets change the settings again

```
Hector:~ robertj$ ulimit -n 512
Hector:~ robertj$ ulimit -a | grep open
open files                      (-n) 512
```

Again that works fine nicely. Lets change again to some higher value

```
Hector:~ robertj$ ulimit -n 1024
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
Hector:~ robertj$
```

What the f*** is this now?

If I try to sudo this I dont get an error but the value doesnt get changed either.

```
Hector:~ robertj$ sudo ulimit -n 1024
Password:
Hector:~ robertj$ ulimit -a | grep open
open files                      (-n) 512
Hector:~ robertj$
```

What is going on here?

I am completely stumped!

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Robertj

Answer (score 20):

There are two things confusing you.  The first is that there are both hard and soft limits for each resource.  `ulimit -n 512` sets *both* of them, but `ulimit -a` only shows the soft limit.  Once the hard limit is set, it can only be decreased.

```
$ ulimit -n
256
$ ulimit -Hn  # There's no initial hard limit
unlimited
$ ulimit -n 512  # This sets both the hard and soft limits
$ ulimit -n
512
$ ulimit -Hn
512
$ ulimit -n 1024  # Once set, the hard limit cannot be increased
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

The second thing that's confusing you is that `sudo ulimit` doesn't do what you think it does.  It spawns a (root) subprocess, sets the open file limits *for that subprocess*, and then exits the subprocess.  The limits are a per-process setting, so sudo'ing a change to them doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Hi Gordon,thanks for the great explanation.
Sadly I can not upvote your answer yet - but it helped a lot!

Comment: so if a hard limit is set, how do we increase the hard limit?

Comment: @greg: I don't think you can -- that's what makes it a hard limit. On some OSes, root can raise the hard limit on other processes, but I don't think even that's possible on OS X.

Comment: Thanks. I accidentally set it too low which pretty much rendered my system unusable. A reboot seemed to fix it.